# nltk.corpus for data science related words?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

from job description I scraped from the internet, I've went through all nlp processes and I've got to place where I found:

```
freq = nltk.FreqDist(lemmatized_list)
most_freq_words = freq.most_common(100)
```

which outputs:

```
[('data', 179),
 ('experience', 86),
 ('work', 78),
 ('business', 71),
 ('team', 59),
 ('learn', 56),
 ('model', 49),
 ('skills', 47),
 ('science', 41),
 ('use', 41),
 ('build', 39),
 ('machine', 37),
 ('ability', 36),.....
```

and so on. My problem is I do not want to consider words like "experience", "work", and only consider keywords related to data science. I'm guessing there is a corpus for data science terms which I can use like how I use stop word corpus to not select them. Let me know if there is a way, Thanks!

Comment: If you have access to many non-datascience job postings too, you can use some sort of tfidf to down-weight words common in everything.

Comment: But job descriptions on same job will have many occurences of technical skill words in each job description and that would be down-weighted.

Answer (score 1):

I have a way through which you can solve your problem. For it you will require a,

- A pretrained embedding generator. It can be **Word2Vec or GloVe**. Any of them could work.

> Next, we have a corpus of words which have higher frequencies. Suppose
>   we have a set of 100 such words where the 1st word has the highest
>   frequency.

Now, we convert every word in this set to a vector using our pretrained word embedding. 
Hence you will have a set of vectors for the words from the corpus. Let's call it $z_i$

We have the word "data science". Get a vector for this too. Let's call it $x$

1. Measure the euclidean distance between the vector $x$ and $z_i$.
2. Or, you can measure cosine similarity betwee $x$ and $z_i$.
3. Both of above methods will produce a set of values which would show proximity of $x$ with values of $z_i$.
4. From these 100 values, we get the least 10 values and convert them to words again.

**These 10 words would have the highest similarity with the word "data science".**

Answer (score 1):

Overall, I agree with Andy M's suggestion.

To address the issue you point out and get rid of words *work* and *experience*, you can probably ignore the n-most-frequent words in the general corpus that **also** appear in the data science corpus, and keep the rest as the data-science-related terms.

So, in a more pythonic way:

```
general_texts = [
    ['a', 'sentence', 'about', 'experience'],
    ['another', 'sentence', 'typed', 'at', 'work'],
    ['work', 'experience'],
    ...
]


data_science_texts = [
    ['data', 'science', 'experience'],
    ['work', 'on', 'machine', 'learning'],
    ...
]

freqdist_gnrl = Counter()
freqdist_ds = Counter()

for text in general_texts:
    freqdist_gnrl.update(text)

for text in data_science_texts:
    freqdist_ds.update(text)

mostfreq_words_gnrl = freqdist_gnrl.most_common(2)   # 'work', 'experience'

words_ds = [
    w for w, _ in freqdist_ds.most_common()
    if w not in mostfreq_words_gnrl        # every word other than 'work' or 'experience'
]
```

In this example, I have used `2` as *n* for the *n*-most frequent terms to make it work but, over a larger corpus, you can probably take a few hundred words.

After applying this filter, the first *k* words in the variable `words_ds` should all be related to data science to a reasonable extent.

Hope this helps!